# Writing a nested list in Python in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like:
    a = [(a,[1,2,3]),(b,[4,5,6)].

How can I write the above list in a txt file like:

```
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
```

in a most pythonic way?
Thanks

Comment: Are `a` and `b` strings or variables?

Comment: @AndrewL. all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    for elem in a:
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(elem[0], ' '.join(str(i) for i in elem[1])))
```